# How to save password in SSIS package configuration using Visual Studio 2005 BIDS?

Tags: sql-server-2005, configuration, ssis, package-management

I know this isn't a "good" thing to do, but its also a temporary measure on several internal servers used by a select few developers. So please forgive me engaging in "very bad things" :)

The crux of the problem can be seen when I open any of my connection managers: the password field is empty. I am using SQL Server Authentication with SS 2005 and VS 2005 BIDS. So, is it even possible to save passwords in an XML package configuration (*.dtsConfig) and maintain them across machines and servers unencrypted?

Thanks for all for the help!

Comment: Should take this over to http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: I brought it over here because I saw a lot of questions being asked about MS SQL server stuff. Sorry for the confusion. I'm a regular on stackoverflow lately :) I read the FAQ, and I'm guessing this forum is more for "How do I configure my server?" rather than "How do I program software to automate a script on a database server?" Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BIDS won't save passwords for you, but you can open the package configuration file and enter them manually:

http://wiki.sqlis.com/default.aspx/SQLISWiki/PackageConfigurations.html